# mapping GET query with spring and tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-mapping

Searching since yesterday, but I only get adance method.
I use spring with tomcat and I want to handle the get paramter. But for that what I need first is to succefully map the url. (an example, /store.htm?id=X)
At the begining I match every .htm url with

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my web.xml

I handle them with for example

```
<bean name="/main.htm" class="package.to.my.Controller">
<property name="aManager" ref="aManager"/>
</bean>
```

and it works, but when I want to use some get parameter with an url like /store.htm?id=X
the mapping didn't work anymore.

I tryed several pattern like

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm?id=*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or

```
<url-pattern>*.htm*
```

nothing seems to work..
How could I handle that ?

(I based myself on the tutorial of spring 2.5 on the official website).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping doesn't care about the query string. It only cares about the path of the URL. A request to `/main.htm?id=foo` will be mapped to `myapp` since `*.htm` is mapped to `myapp`.

Comment: my problem was more about how to fill >the bean name=" "> attribute, 
I tried with /store.htm and it works actually...